# How to put the text with rigorous orientation on 3d surface?

Tags: python, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to plot 3d surface with text.

For example let's consider surface described by eq. z = 1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1])
y = np.array([0, 1])

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.ones((2,2))

# Create a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.7)

# Set the labels
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Further I would like to add text to this surface at the coordinate (0.5,0.5,1). Text should printed strictly on this surface and oriented at an angle of 45 like that:

[image]

Unfortunately, I haven't found any satisfactory solution of this problem in matplotlib functional. I tried simple `ax.text(0.5,0.5,1, "Text", fontsize = 20)`, but it's far from the result I'm trying to achieve. (Text nether belongs to the surface nor has the proper orientation, see below)

[image]

Please, help me!